# Dismiss rootViewController on UIApplicationWillTerminate

Tags: ios, swift, retain-cycle, application-lifecycle

When trying to dismiss root view controller;

This code works in other functions but not in a function which is get called by UIApplicationWillTerminate notification.

```
    let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDel.window?.rootViewController = nil
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

I have failed to detect any retain cycle.
Can somebody please help?

Comment: If `UIApplicationWillTerminate` is being called then your app is being fully terminated by iOS. There's no need to clean up any memory. It's all going to be cleaned by iOS. And there's no need to dismiss any views since your app won't be running at all any more.

Comment: In theory yes, but somehow old instance of rootViewController remains when app is relaunched after app gets terminated by swiping up. This is why i wanted to dismiss before termination.

Comment: Nothing remains after terminating by swiping up. On next launch your app is being fully launched from scratch. Anything you see at that point has nothing to do with how the app looked before being terminated.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I assumed that it somehow remained in the memory because, when i logout after launching app, everything is fine. However if user launches the app then kills the app and relaunches and logout, not everything is deinitialized. On next login attempt  after redirected to login, App crashes due to Optional nil error caused by UserDefaults. This feels so weird.

Comment: Sounds like the issue is with how you load userdefaults checking for previous values. Can you post that code?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you actually have is a mistreated UserDefaults initialization. Perhaps you save some data along the user's session into the device storage for consumption at a later stage, but somehow you either forgot to properly clean that data, or tried to initialize it again without properly unwrapping the optionals returned by UserDefaults methods.

Try checking your code for any force-unwrapped instances of data and do the proper error handling for them. If this is the problem, it will go away.